# How to suppress Warning--empty author Message?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am citing the IEEE-754 standard and it doesn't have an author. However, when I generate my PDF, the tool I am using (texnixcenter) provides a warning that there is no author. I would like to know how to get rid of this warning?

Here is the IEEE-754 standard bibtex entry that I have:

```
@ARTICLE{ieee754std,
journal={IEEE Std 754-2008}, 
title={{IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic}}, 
year={2008}, 
pages={1-70}, 
keywords={IEEE standards;floating point arithmetic;programming;IEEE standard;arithmetic formats;computer programming;decimal floating-point arithmetic;754-2008;NaN;arithmetic;binary;computer;decimal;exponent;floating-point;format;interchange;number;rounding;significand;subnormal}, 
doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.2008.4610935},}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `@manual` be a more appropriate entry rather than `@article`?

Comment: I downloaded the bibtex entry from IEEE, so I left it as article.

Comment: It is not an article and “IEEE Std 754-2008” is not a journal. Whatever IEEE thinks of it, classifying this entry as an article is wrong. What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: I'm using IEEEtran

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bibliography item is wrongly classified. In my opinion it should be

```
@manual
```

or

```
@booklet
```

Here's how I'd code it (without any warning):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{ieee754std,
  note={{IEEE Std 754-2008}},
  title={{IEEE} Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic},
  year={2008},
  pages={1-70},
  keywords={IEEE standards;floating point arithmetic;
            programming;IEEE standard;arithmetic formats;
            computer programming;decimal floating-point arithmetic;
            754-2008;NaN;arithmetic;binary;computer;decimal;exponent;
            floating-point;format;interchange;number;rounding;
            significand;subnormal},
  doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.2008.4610935},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{ieee754std}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note that `filecontents*` is just for the example, you can use your `.bib` file as usual.

[image]

Comment: Now the pages field disappeared

Comment: @sphere The manual having 70 pages is not a relevant information.

Comment: K, I saw it referenced like that (1-70) or (1-55) in other papers though.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution is to use `@misc`:

- The title of the standard is not "bolded"
- It gives you the pages and the same format of the `@article`
- ... and it is error-free