# Warning--empty institution and Warning--empty journal

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, google-scholar

I am having a problem citing some of my references in a chapter of my dissertation.I get two error messages when I try to compile the Reference.bib file namely Warning--empty journal for a research paper found on google scholar [here](https://scholar.google.co.za/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Multisensor%20concealed%20weapon%20detection%20using%20the%20image%20fusion%20approach&btnG=) and the error Warning--empty institution for a report found [here](https://scholar.google.co.za/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Crime%20in%20England%20and%20Wales%2C%20Year%20Ending%20June%202013&btnG=).

Due to these warnings my references appear wrongly e.g if I put references before the reference giving a warning, the order of referencing changes when I compile the document. Thus the citation reference number 1 becomes reference 2 and so on.

I am using TeXShop version 3.77 on a Mac.

I have tried suggestions from the following posts with no luck :[Stop bibtex from complaining about an empty note](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40189/stop-bibtex-from-complaining-about-an-empty-note), [BibTeX is not parsing my entries correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48326/bibtex-is-not-parsing-my-entries-correctly) and [How to suppress Warning--empty author Message?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129643/how-to-suppress-warning-empty-author-message)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\include{titlepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\setcounter{chapter}{+5}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter5}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add the both bib entrys you have problems with to **your question**!

Comment: Examples for different citing options that you can use instead of article:
https://verbosus.com/bibtex-style-examples.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you have discovered is that bibliographic information obtained from Google Scholar can contain serious mistakes -- both semantic and factual. For instance, the first link you provided leads to the following bibliographic entry:

```
@article{xu2015multisensor,
  title={Multisensor concealed weapon detection using the image fusion approach},
  author={Xu, Tuzhi and Wu, QM Jonathan},
  year={2015},
  publisher={IET}
}
```

In a narrow sense, BibTeX -- actually, the `plain` bibliography style -- is throwing a warning message (not an error message) because entries of type `@article` *require* a non-empty `journal` field. For the `plain` bibliography style, the four *required* fields for entries of type `@article` are `author`, `title`, `journal`, and `year`; the four *optional* fields are `volume`, `number`, `pages`, and `note`. Note that for the `@article` entry type, the `publisher` field is neither required nor optional; therefore, it is ignored entirely.

In a broader sense, though, the BibTeX/`plain` warning arises because the entry in question should not have been classified as being of type `@article` to begin with, as it wasn't published in an academic journal. A quick glance suggests that the entry type `@inproceedings` may be correct. *You* will have to perform the research to find out which entry type is actually appropriate here. (I assume you have access to the published piece -- I don't.)

Moral of the story: Do not place blind faith in the correctness of *any* bibliographic information obtained from Google Scholar. You read correctly: All information obtained from Google Scholar is *potentially suspect and must be verified*. This caution applies not only to those entries for which BibTeX throws outright errors or warnings. "Passing the BibTeX test" indicates merely that no *semantic* issues -- such as missing `journal` fields -- are present. You still have to be concerned about possible *factual* errors in all entries.

Comment: thank you that explanation is just what the doctor ordered. It solved the problem for me.